# Bind treeview with values of one column of a table as parent node and other column values as Child node in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, treeview

Well for example, I have a table named Country and it has two columns Country name and city name,  in column 'country name' i have name of different countries and in column 'city name' I have name of cities. If the value in country name column is USA than the value in city name column will be any city of USA not anything else, the table is structured that way. So now I want to bind treeview with this table like

- Country

  - USA

    - New York
    - Washington
  - Australia

    - Sydney
    - Melbourne

means to add child nodes (cities) against their respective country name. How can i achieve this in vb.net. Please can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

"select city from Country where country = @country"

will get you the data you want.

"select country, city from Country order by country"

will get you the data in order so you can build a tree view, jumping to a new node when the country name changes.

You have not indicated if you're using web or windows, winforms or WPF, ASP.NET or MVC, so it's really hard to give any more info than that.